# Fermat's Little Theorem and prime divisors

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, divisibility, square-numbers

Let $a,b\in\Bbb N$ and $a+b$ be an even number.

**Assume** $a^2 - b^2 - a$ is an exact square, say $c^2$.

Let $m = \frac {a+b}2$ and $n = \frac {a-b}2$.

Then,

$$(4m-1)(4n-1) = 4(4mn-m-n) + 1 = 4(a^2-b^2-a)+1=(2c)^2+1^2 $$

My **2** questions are:

1. Why does $(2c)^2+1$ have a prime divisor of the form $4k-1$?
2. Why does it follow from the Fermat's Little Theorem that $4k-1$ divides $2c$ and $1$(**thus contradiction**)?

Comment: How do you get question part (2) from FMT?

Comment: what do you mean by FMT?

Comment: Oh sorry! I mean FLT (Fermat's Little Theorem).

Comment: Actually, that is the question, how does it follow. I am told that if follows but can't see why.

Answer (score 0):

Part (1) can be done by a descent type argument.

If a number $N$ has a factor $4k-1$ then either this is prime and we're done or it factorises into two factors $p$ and $q$ with $1 \lt (p, q)\lt N$.

Consider multiplication modulo 4 to get to $4k-1$, which is $3 \mbox{ mod } 4$ we need one of $p, q$ is $3 \mbox{ mod } 4$ and the other is $1 \mbox{ mod } 4$.

WLOG take $p = 3 \mbox{ mod } 4 = 4j-1$ and we are back where we started but with a smaller integer. This process must terminate as the smallest positive integer of this form is $3$ itself.

Thus $2c^2+1$ has a prime divisor of the form $4k-1$.